# Ring homomorphism - isomorphic subring

Tags: ring-theory

Please help me with this exercise.

Let $K$ be a field, $A$ a ring (without the assumption that a ring must have an identity) and $\phi : K \longrightarrow A$ an homomorphism.

Prove either $A$ must contain a subring isomorphic to $K$ or $\phi$ is identically zero.

---

Now, I know, $\phi (K)$ is a subring of $A$, but it would only be isomorphic to $K$ if $\phi $ was injective, so I'm sort of stuck..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\ker(\phi)$ is an ideal of the field $K$, hence ...

Comment: Oh I get it.. The only ideals of a field $K$ are $\{ 0 \}$ and $K$ itself, therefore $\ker{(\phi)}$ must be one of those.

If $\ker{(\phi)}={0}$ then $\phi$ is injective and the subring $\phi (K)$ of $A$ is isomorphic to $K$.

On the other hand if $\ker{(\phi )}=A$, then obviously $\phi $ is identically zero, completing the proof.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, that's it. :)

Comment: edit: I meant $\ker{(\phi)} = K$ on the last line and $\ker{(\phi)} = \{ 0 \}$ on the second line.